# Starting text a set distance from the margin

Tags: spacing, indentation

I want to break some lines in a document into 3 sections such that the first letter of each section is always directly below the other, slightly like a table, but I don't want to use the table environnment.

My current code is:

```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \linespread{1.25}
  \usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{changepage}
  \begin{document}
  \normalsize\textbf{Book title}\hspace{3.3cm}\textbf{Author's name}\hspace{5.4cm} 2010\\
  \hangindent=4.25cm
  \hangafter=0 This book is about some guy who wrote a book because he felt like a book would be a good thing to write.....etc etc etc
  \normalsize\textbf{Book title 2}\hspace{3.1cm}\textbf{Longer Author's name}\hspace{4.9cm} 1991\\
  \hangindent=4.25cm 
  \hangafter=0 This book is about a woman.....etc etc

  \end{document}
```

As you can see I have placed \hspace commands mid line to produce the required spacing, but it's very tedious to do this for many enteries. Is there a better way that doesn't involve using the table environment?

[image]

Comment: I added an image of your document. Could you confirm that's really the layout you want with longer author's name wrapping to the start of the next line?

Comment: why don't you want to use a table (or tabbing) ?

Answer (score 4):

One non-tabular approach using  the `tabto` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabto}
\parindent0pt
\parskip.5em
\begin{document}
\NumTabs{3}

\noindent {\bfseries Book title} \tab{\bfseries Author's name} \tab{2010}

This book is about some guy who wrote a book because he felt like a book would be a good thing to write.....etc etc etc

{\bfseries Book title 2} \tab{\bfseries Longer Author's name} \tab{1991}

This book is about a woman\ldots etc. etc.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

However, note that this could be the wrong way if you have some very long names. In this case you can use `\parbox` and `\hfill`. Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\def\tab#1{\parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}{#1}\hfill}
\parindent0pt
\parskip.5em
\begin{document}

\tab{\bfseries Book title} \tab{\bfseries Author's name} \tab{2010}

This book is about some guy who wrote a book because he felt like a book would be a good thing to write.....etc etc etc

\tab{\bfseries Book title 2} \tab{\bfseries Very very very long Author's name} \tab{1991}

This book is about a woman\ldots etc. etc.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

Comment: I think this is the easiest to implement. If I wanted to adjust the tab width, so you might have, across a page, parboxes of 0.1, 0.3 and 0.6. What would I need to do with the code?

I assume I can use a hanging indent for the description text

Comment: @Magiclamarshmallow With some like  `\newcommand\Tab[2]{\tab{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr.#1\linewidth-.7em}{#2}}}` and then  `\NumTabs{10}` you can use custom tabs like `\Tab{3}{Long text}` to have a width nearly to 30% of the line (minus -0.7em because must be some space between tabs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\makebox` to specify the width of the blocks. As the other answer shows, are other box commands that will give you other options like text wrapping (see `texdoc lshort`). If you want the date flush right you can just put an `\hfill` before it.

This will all be simpler to write if you define a macro that spaces and formats your headers so that you can use semantic markup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\pubTitleAuthorYear}[3]{%
    \noindent%
    \makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\textbf{#1}}% book title
    \makebox[\width][l]{\textbf{#2}}% author name
    \hfill%
    #3% year
    \smallskip\par%
}
\newcommand{\pubInfo}[1]{\noindent #1\medskip\par}

\begin{document}

\pubTitleAuthorYear{Book One}{Author One}{2010}
\pubInfo{\lipsum[1]}

\pubTitleAuthorYear{Book Two}{Author Two}{2011}
\pubInfo{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

You could substitute the widths of the boxes and the formatting of their contents with separate macros if you wanted easier configuration of the layout. E.g., `\newlength{\bookTitleWidth} \setlength{\bookTitleWidth}{0.5\textwidth}` and `\newcommand{\bookTitleFont}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}`.

[image]